# Automatic cleanup of transaction resources in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(resource);` and I assumed that after a transaction is completed, the resources get cleaned up as well. (They are stored in a thread-local and it doesn't make sense to keep them, and therefore - have the thread dirty).

However it turns out on completion spring only clears transaction sycnrhonization (callbacks), and not resources.

Am I correct in that observation and how to make spring automatically cleanup the bound resources when a transaction completes?

Comment: I haven't look at this logic in a while, but it looks like most transactional managers do call doUnbindResource in doCleanupAfterCompletion - which should clear the resources that were bound. Is that what you're looking at, or am I missing the gist of the question?